# How to merge all records by their unique ID in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame of about a million records with multiple columns including a column for unique_id. This column has about 500,000 unique IDs. I want to aggregate the information of the 10+ columns in a single row per unique id. Ideally, it'd be a string concatenation with a  `,`  between the groups. I have done a groupby on my id column but I'm not sure where to go from here. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
df.groupby('unique_id').agg(', '.join)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).